# How can I use shadow from environment world (HDRI)?

Tags: rendering, animation, shadows, eevee-render-engine

I make an animation in Blender 2.79 and render it using EEVEE in Blender 2.8 as it's very fast. One problem is that if I use HDRI whenever I do this for background, shadow of mesh doesn't appear on other meshes. It does appear when I use the lamp. The best example describing this is following video. You can see that no shadows under human and punching machine. Is there something wrong with the Blender version I'm using or should I do something else to get the shadows?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDgBqsjVR3o

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkVNmjzO1c2Mo0bhR12UwmaU_FsG8tL2/view?usp=sharing) is the *.blend* file I used to render.

Comment: Please attach your .blend and File>External Data>Pack all into .blend, so we can see for our selves, there are so many things that can go wrong, we would have to throw wild guesses at you which would waste your and our time.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I've edited your question with the download link from your other question. Please feel free to edit at any time via the edit button under your post, and/or roll back my edits if you disagree with them. Also see [the help page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) for more info.

Comment: HDRI do NOT cast shadows in EEVEE, You have to fake it with lights.