# Eevee is not showing shadows in viewport, but they are present in the final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, eevee-render-engine, hdri

I am using an HDRi to light my scene and I noticed EEVEE not rendering shadows in the viewport so I was assuming it wouldn't show them in the final render either. On the other side, with Cycles they are shown in the viewport as in the final render.
It turns out that EEVEE is rendering shadows in the final render. Am I missing something or is it normal? May I enable HDRI-based shadows in the viewport or disable them in the final render?

Comment: It is not currently supported but I cannot find any information whether or not it will be supported out of beta. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118087/how-can-i-use-shadow-from-environment-world-hdri https://blenderartists.org/t/eevee-shadows-from-hdri-direct-light/1134748 https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/83ql1q/does_eevee_support_hdr_shadows_yet/

Comment: That was what I knew so far, but Eevee actually RENDERS shadows in final renderings, it is only in the viewport that they are not shown. From what I knew so far (and it is what the questions you mentioned, @rob, are saying) it is Eevee itself that is not able to render shadows from HDRI environment maps (and what you had to do was to add a lamp to add them): but what I see now is that Eevee **is** able to do shadows (in the final render).